# Is there a way to know if a service was running before an app is updated?

Tags: android, service

In my app I'm registering the MY_PACKAGE_UPDATED event in order to restart the background service when the app is updated.

Just before start the app update Android kills the app (UI and background services without call the onDestroy events on Activity/Service). After that, the APK is updated and finally the MY_PACKAGE_UPDATED event is triggered.

Is there a way to known if a concrete Service from the app was running just before the update process starts?

Comment: use broadcast receiver to check app is upadating event. just before event check your service is running or not

Comment: What is this event? ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED ?